# Go missing returns are driving me crazy

Tags: function, go, slice

I'm trying to learn Go and it's going very well except for the functions return statements, which I cannot for my life get a grasp on.
In an exercise in a book it is proposed to construct a function that halves an int and return the halved int and if even or odd (the halved) with a bool. No problems with that, here is the relevant code.

```
func checker(input int) (int, bool){
    if (((input /2) % 2) == 0) {
        return input / 2, true
    } else {
        return input / 2, false
    }
}
```

But when trying to convert this to accept a slice I swear I cannot understand where the returns are missing. Here again is the relevant code for that:

```
func checker(args ...int) (int, bool){
    for _, v := range args {
        if (((v /2) % 2) == 0) {
            return v / 2, true
        } else {
            return v / 2, false
        }
    }
}

func main () {
    xs := []int{3,45,6,32,43,76,42,4,77,8}
    fmt.Println(checker(xs...))
}
```

I think now I understand several of the problems of the code I presented, thank you for your responses.

Comment: You slice version doesn't make sense for several reasons, and the return is missing if for example the slice that is passed in is empty.

Comment: @super I assume it's stupid because I'm sure there's a better way to do it, but I asked in order to understand how the returns worked by taking what I know about go to the "extreme" (my short-sighted extreme in this case). Sorry if it bothered you.

Comment: If passing 0 args is invalid, `panic` a panic at the end of the function indicating the invalid call won't require a return

Comment: @Vvyibaba It didn't bother me at all, on the contrary, that's what asking question here are all about. I just wanted to make you aware that other then the missing return at the end there are additional issues with you function. This was also pointed out in the answer by icza. The loop will always return on the first iteration and therefor only ever check the first element of the slice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no guarantee `checker()` gets more than **zero** arguments, in which case the loop body would be executed zero times, so no `return` statements would be reached.

So the compiler is rightful to complain about a missing return, as this condition is decided at runtime.

E.g. if you pass `0` arguments: `checker()`, it's valid and would cause problem if a `return` would not be demanded.

So simply add a `return` statement with reasonable return values, often the zero values of the result types:

```
func checker(args ...int) (int, bool){
    for _, v := range args {
        if (((v /2) % 2) == 0) {
            return v / 2, true
        } else {
            return v / 2, false
        }
    }
    return 0, false
}
```

Also note that this loop only checks the first passed argument and returns, probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried to implement a check about that but didn't know how to not return anything if that was the case and throw an error. the check went something like this: `func checker(args ...int) (int, bool){
    if  (len(args) == 0){
    // the code to escape
    } else {
    //the previous for loop
    }
}``` Is this not sufficient?

Comment: `func checker(args ...int) (int, bool){ if (len(args) == 0){ // the code to escape } else { //the previous for loop } }` (hope it detects it as code)

Comment: You do not need to detect it. Just add a proper `return` statement with reasonable values, e.g. with the zero values.

Comment: Implementing the fix suggested by everyone about adding an idiotic return drew my attention about the non functioning for, another thing to worry about given that is code taken (and adapted a little bit) for another part of said book. I'll look up why that is, but that's another question in itself.

Comment: I suppose it only returns the first because in this case the return "completes" the function and doesn't execute any further.

Answer (score 1):

You return only in the For loop Scope. Return after the for loop. If your args are empty, then your loop does not run and no returns reached. So you need to add a return after for loop.

I suggest handle this as an error scenario or something. Below I have mention the simple solution for this.

```
func checker(args ...int) (int, bool){
    for _, v := range args {
        if ((v /2) % 2 == 0) {
            return v / 2, true
        } else {
            return v / 2, false
        }
    }
    return 0, false
}
```

Comment: If i understand correctly in your example we would treat that as an idiotic return and filter it in the main(), but when not expecting any idiotic response and a similiar loop is in place, how would it be handled? Example: a variadic function that halves any float and returns the result.

Comment: you need to return error, like  "sent array length must be greater than zero"